# Stop the time within the test in Hardhat (Solidity)

Tags: testing, time, solidity, hardhat

Is it possible to stop the time within the test, until the time is changed manually via "evm_increaseTime" in Hardhat?
For example when we increase time by 1 second:

```js
await ethers.provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [1]);
await ethers.provider.send('evm_mine');
```

After that we somehow stop the time within the test. Has anybody had similar problem or know the solution to that?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. You need to set the `automine` mode to false:

```js
await ethers.provider.send("evm_setAutomine", [false]);
```

This stops your local blockchain from mining blocks and increasing time automatically after every transaction.

ref. https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#evm-setautomine.